# Understanding RxJS debounce semantics

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rxjs

From [this article](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html):

```
 const debouncedInput = example.debounceTime(5);

 const subscribe = debouncedInput.subscribe(val => {
   console.log(`Debounced Input: ${val}`);
 });
```

After the first keyup will the `debouncedInput` wait to call the observer for 5 milliseconds?

Also suppose the user keeps typing before the 5 millisecond interval expires.  Does the `debouncedInput` Observable wait until an uninterrupted 5 millisecond period passes before publishing the event / source value?

In terms of an example (Per the very helpful marble diagram in @OJKwon s answer)  suppose the `-` represents a millisecond.  And we have the following:

```
 -a--b--c-------d
```

In this case the timer that monitors the interval will be restarted at:

- 2 ms when a is typed
- 5 ms when b is typed
- 8 ms when c is typed
- 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ms pass
- `abc` gets emitted at 13 ms because there was not other event in that period
- The timer starts again when `d` is typed at 14 ms
- `abcd` is emitted at 19 ms because no other value is typed

Comment: It's yes to both questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the `debounceTime` operator does is delay the source observable emission by the specified timeframe. If another source value is emitted during the delay it:

- Drops previous value
- Resets the interval timer
- Wait to see whether the interval will pass without more source values being emitted.
- Finally if the are no values emitted during the interval it will emit the last value.

RxJSs [marble test diagram](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/operators/debounceTime-spec.ts) illustrates this quite well.  Lets review a few cases.

#### When we have `source.debountTime(20)`,

1. all source value emission occurs after 20

`const source =   '-a--------b------'; 
 const expected = '---a--------b----';`

all of source values are just simply delayed.

2. if some source value emitted subsequently in 20ms

`const source =   '-a--bc--d---|';
const expected =  '---a---c--d-|';`

emitted `a` delayed by 20ms, `b` dropped since `c` emitted before timespan of 20ms for next emission, then `d` is delayed by 20ms after `c` does.

To summarize the `debounceTime` operator functions as a rate limiter only allowing a single value to be emitted in given timeframe.

Comment: Awesome the marble test diagram was really helpful!  I updated the question a bit using the format.